# How to reduce the DOMContentLoaded Time using Angular2

Tags: angular, domcontentloaded

I am converting a template (Dashboard like) from JQuery to Angular 2. The website have lot of popups and these popups have many tabs so I put each popup in different component to maintain its code and logic separately. Now if I observe the Network tab in chrome then it can be seen that the major delay is the DOMContentLoaded delay.

So my question is this how to reduce this delay in this kind of situation.

[Image of Network tab from Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grIxO.png)

This page contain just a single signup and forgot form.

Comment: build it with AOT https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

Comment: Yes, I provided link for it

Comment: Can you please tell me how dramatically it can reduce this domLoaded Time?

Comment: If you are not going to use those popups straight after page loads you can set up custom preloading strategy. Custom preloading strategy loads defined modules after the initial page load. Similarly there is lazy loading

Comment: Because, when you use JIT compilation, browser compiles JS code in runtime and DomLoaded time is increasing until compilation complete. In AOT case you already have compiled code and it executes 'immediately'.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Anton

Comment: Also you can move your popups in different modules and load them lazily as @mxr7350 said

Comment: I am getting this error in the step of bootstrapping when importing AppModuleNgFactory and using it in bootstrap. any solutions?

Argument of type 'NgModuleFactory<AppModule>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Type<{}>'.

Comment: Changes .bootstrapModule() to .bootstrapModuleFactory() solve the above issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my jquery template there are lots of (10) modals which are following Bootstrap modals to make some parts of templates working.

After just deleting them my issue is resolved now the loading time is following

[Image of Network Tab in Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4DVD.png)